# Replace HTML tag with text Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular6

I want to change a specific word in my code with HTML tag and change style of my text with **themecolor** class.

```
<h2 class="mb-30" [innerHTML]="main_title"></h2>
```

Preview of result:

> This is text.

I want to replace `<span class="themecolor">text</span>` with `text`.

I built my application with Angular 6

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need such functionality since Angular is component based where you have html injected via selectors.

Anyway,
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdbrrq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

The bindind occures as you wanted in this line:

```
<h2 class="mb-30" [innerHTML]="main_title"></h2>
```

All I do is instantiating **main_title** with custom HTML of your choice in **app.component.ts**

Also, please note that I used **ngDoCheck** in order to detect changes on the text input.

This will allow you to enter **HTML** inside the textbox (preferred as textarea actually).

Comment: i want to change stye of my text with css. this is not my answer @monogate

Answer (score 0):

use Renderer 2 in [@angular/core](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)

ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-html',
  templateUrl: './app-custom-html.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-custom-html.component.scss']
})
export class CustomHtmlComponent implements OnInit
{

  @Input() public text: string;
  @ViewChild('container') public container: ElementRef;
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit()
  {
    const span = this.renderer.createElement('span');
    this.renderer.addClass(span, 'my-class');
    const text = this.renderer.createText(v.text);
    this.renderer.appendChild(span, text);

    this.renderer.appendChild(this.container.nativeElement, div);
  }
}
```

HTML file

```
<div #container></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
property: string = "Text";

Use [innerText]="property"
<p [innerText]="property/variable"></p>
```

This will insert the text into your html